# Security of sha1 hashed password in memory

Tags: c++, security, hash, mfc, reverse-engineering

My program allows the user to input a password. The password is immediately hashed with sha1 and a constant salt and stored in memory.
Lets assume an Attacker has physical access to the computer where my application runs, and wants to retrieve the password of the last user.

Would it be possible for him to find the hash in memory with reverse engineering and some memory watch magic? My Application uses a MFC graphical interface and runs on Windows. What would he see if he himself puts in a password? could he monitor the hashing process?

If the password of my user is really bad, like "1234", all the security of the SHA1 hash depends on the SALT. The salt must also be stored somewhere in memory (its a #defined char* array right now). Could he find that with adequate effort?

**Input process:**

User enters password in a text edit. When done, user clicks "OK" button, `BN_CLICKED` message gets emitted, `OnOK` function is called. The function grabs text from edit field, calls hash function, which is (in code) part of another library, so I assume it must be placed somewhere else in memory. Hashed String gets stored also somewhere else. If it matters, the project structure looks like this:

- SOLUTION

  - GUI Project
  - Data Storage Project
  - Crypto Lib

Comment: If I wanted to steal the password, I would simply "steal" it from the edit input field without bothering finding hashes somewhere in memory. A part from that the answer is probably "yes".

Comment: @MichaelWalz Please assume that the attacker is not at the same time with the user at the application. And the edit field gets cleared after every entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse engineer Win32/MFC applications then you should notice those data are stored in .data section while const data are stored in .rdata section, not unless the developer has explicitly created another section to store those data. I use OllyDbg for reverse engineering applications though IDA is the best one out there. Now to answer your question:

**Would it be possible for him to find the hash in memory with reverse engineering and some memory watch magic? My Application uses a MFC graphical interface and runs on Windows. What would he see if he himself puts in a password? could he monitor the hashing process?**

A: Yes, it is possible to find the hash in memory with reverse engineering. You just have to find the memory address of that data. Any reverse engineer/hacker can put a break point in GetDlgItem/GetDlgItemText and then capture the entered password and monitor the hashing process.

**If the password of my user is really bad, like "1234", all the security of the SHA1 hash depends on the SALT. The salt must also be stored somewhere in memory (its a #defined char* array right now). Could he find that with adequate effort?**

A: It requires very little effort to find the SALT too. One can easily go through those sections or use the technique that I mentioned above to debug and find out the SALT while monitoring the process.

If you are really worried about securing those data then you should consider using encryption. I hope that answers your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Asesh. If I follow you correctly, every in-memory-saved data is readable for an attacker. I agree. How easy is it to find a constant encryption key somewhere stored in memory, if I don't know its value? If it is easy, how does any encryption has any use if I can extract the key from memory?

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to find encryption key stored in memory. Guessing by going through data sections won't be easy so a reverse engineer will have to reverse engineer and step through the disassembled code to find it. Finding the memory location of that key shouldn't be difficult either but if that key is encrypted then a hacker will have to find out a way to decrypt it. I don't have so much experience with encryption but Windows provides APIs for encryption: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255(v=vs.85).aspx might be helpful to you :)

Comment: Fill the char* buffer with zeroes using the [SecureZeroMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877(v=vs.85).aspx) function after use.